# jQuery: get content / innerhtml onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you click on a cell on [this page](http://rageheaven.com/new), it loads the larger version of the image. I'm trying to achieve this same effect.

What I have gotten so far: http://jsfiddle.net/8mYW9/

First off I know having the `"appear" <div>` is redundant - is there a good way to utilize `$(this)` and `appendTo();` instead?

Ultimately my idea is to grab the id of the anchor contained within the div that is clicked and to append it to the cell. What should I be doing...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the ID attribute to class for the `appear` elements you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#appear').hide();
    $('.links').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);//cache the $(this) selector since it will be used more than once
        $this.children('.appear').html('item id: ' + $this.children('a').attr('id')).fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8mYW9/7/

BTW you can't have multiple elements with the same ID in a HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#appear').hide();
    $('.links').click(function() {
        $(this).append('<div>' + $(this).find('a:first').attr('id') + '</div>');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8mYW9/4/).

Amended so that only *one* `id` is shown (others are removed before showing the latest):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#appear').hide();
    $('.links').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.container').find('.appended').remove();
        $(this).append('<div class="appended">' + $(this).find('a:first').attr('id') + '</div>');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8mYW9/5/).

Incidentally, it escaped my notice the first time, but with multiple elements sharing the *same `id`* you have invalid (X)HTML: an `id` ***must be*** unique within the document (citation: [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using class selectors instead. You've got duplicate IDs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.appear').hide();
    $('.links').click(function() {
        $(this).find(".appear").fadeToggle('slow', function() {
            $(this).html('item id:')
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8mYW9/