# Getting handle on the calling html element using javascript or dojo or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><span onClick='toggleFunction();'>ABC</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span onClick='toggleFunction();'>PQR</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span onClick='toggleFunction();'>XYZ</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span onClick='toggleFunction();'>LMN</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

The HTML is dynamically generated.

```
function toggleFunction() {
  var innerHtml = //code to get inner html of calling element here
  console.log(innerHtml);
}
```

I want to get the inner html of `span` from which `toggleFunction()` is invoked through `onClick`.

For e.g. when the click is on row 1, `ABC` should get printed on console. But when the click is on row 3, `XYZ` should be printed.

Is this possible through Javascript or Dojo? I can not use Jquery. However, I would like to know if this is possible using Jquery or not.

Please note that the `span` element is without any id.

This is not a duplicate of other question as:

1) The accepted solution uses inline javascript just to alert innerHTML. However, for me, I just want a way to gain a Handle, so that I can do far more required processing inside my function.

2) Other answers on the question are using element id, which is not my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get innerHTML of this element in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674194/how-to-get-innerhtml-of-this-element-in-javascript) and [Javascript: How to get innerHTML of clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004823/javascript-how-to-get-innerhtml-of-clicked-button)

Comment: @adiga This is not a duplicate question. Better read the question first guys. Do not over monitor and discourage questions.

Comment: use `toggleFunction` instead of `alert`. I found at least 10 duplicates.

Comment: The answer is simply `var innerHtml = event.target.innerHTML;`

Comment: @adiga: Really? Where are the question which answers my question. If `toggleFunction` is in a separate file, console.log(this.innerHTML) inside toggleFunction does not work. If it does, why not provide a JSFiddle of the same if you feel you know the answer.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: Great. If this works then that is what I was looking for. And none of the other questions have that line as an answer.

Comment: Separate file, same file won't make difference. `console.log(this.innerHTML)` won't work because this refers to the `Window` object and not to your element.

Comment: More duplicates: [jQuery: get content / innerhtml onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685094) and [How to get the innerHTML of selectable jquery element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786050) and [getting inner html of a link when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995501) and [Use jQuery to get text of target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720807)

Comment: @adiga: You really don't get the question. Do you? I have clearly mentioned, there is no id present. All you are redirecting me to are the answers using id or css class name or something like that. Even I can search those. Please let it be. I have got what I was looking for. No need to prove anything.

Comment: [Man, just replace `alert` with your function in the first duplicate](https://jsfiddle.net/rbg8s79k/). Good day.

Comment: Your answer is right in the proposed duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005107/2181514 - add `this`, ie:  `<span onClick='toggleFunction(this);'>` `function toggleFunction(el) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to get innerHTML of clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004823/javascript-how-to-get-innerhtml-of-clicked-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `event.target` to target the clicked element then get the content using `textContent` like :

```
var innerHtml = event.target.textContent;
```

**NOTE 1:** The `td` should be closed before `tr` so use `</td></tr>` at the end instead of `</tr></td>`.

**NOTE 2:** You have a typo in the variable passed to `console.log()`, It should be `innerHtml` instead of `innnerHtml`.

**NOTE 3:** Since you've no HTML inside the columns it will be better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

```js
function toggleFunction() {
  var innerHtml = event.target.textContent;
  console.log(innerHtml);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span onClick='toggleFunction();'>ABC</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span onClick='toggleFunction();'>PQR</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span onClick='toggleFunction();'>XYZ</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span onClick='toggleFunction();'>LMN</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```